# what if i double click on the listbox, then it displays the value in the userform

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

so the listbox is in the userform3. after I do a data search, it will appear in the listbox. when I double click on the listbox, it will show the value of the textbox in userform2. i used this code but it didn't work

```
Dim r, lr as integer
lr= sheet7. Cells(rows.count, 2).end(xlup).row
For r=2 to lr

If sheet7.cells(r, 1).value=listbox1.list(listbox1.listindex, 1) and sheet7.cells(r, 2).value=listbox1.list(listbox1.listindex, 2) then
Unload me
Userform2.Textbox2.value = sheet7.cells(r,1) 
End if
End with
Next r
```

Why that code isn't working? Fyi there are 2 kriteria

Answer (score 0):

too little context for the code you showed

maybe this will help you get on the route

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    
    'define the criteria parameters
    With Me ' reference the parent Userform object
        With .ListBox1
            Dim refVal1 As String, _
                refVal2 As String
                refVal1 = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
                refVal2 = .List(.ListIndex, 2)
        End With
    End With
        
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long
        With Sheet7 ' reference "sheet7" sheet

            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                
            For r = 2 To lr
            
                If .Cells(r, 1).Value = refVal1 And .Cells(r, 2).Value = refVal2 Then
                    UserForm2.TextBox2.Value = .Cells(r, 1) ' hoping UserForm2 has no "Initialize" event active...
                    Exit For
                End If
                
            Next
            unload me 'are you sure you want to unload the parent userform?

        End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Still not working :(